# собираю веб приложнение, и на странице не отображается русский язык

Tags: java, maven, кодировка

Собираю вебАпп, на мавене, запускаю через томкат сервер, открываю страницу, и там вместо рус букв знаки вопроса. Кодировки везде утф8, всё прогуглил, не нашёл работающего ответа.
Если просто запустить хтмл страницу, то всё отображается хорошо.
Вот пом.хмл

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>ru.kutateladze.webEpam</groupId>
  <artifactId>webAppEpam</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>webAppEpam Maven Webapp</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
      <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring5</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.11.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>


  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>webAppEpam</finalName>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
          <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2</version>
          <configuration>
            <port>8080</port>
            <path>/</path>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: мне кажется, дело именно в мавене((

Comment: сам файл веб страницы в какой кодировке?

Comment: @tym32167 utf-8, в начале документа так же указан utf-8

Answer (score 0):

Это можно исправить добавив следующий фильтр:

```
public class AppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    // ...

    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        return new Filter[] { prepareCharacterEncodingFilter() };
    }

    private CharacterEncodingFilter prepareCharacterEncodingFilter() {
        CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
        characterEncodingFilter.setForceEncoding(true);
        return characterEncodingFilter;
    }
}
```

Comment: Добавил это в диспатчер, который уже был, ничего не изменилось. https://github.com/ntnew/example/blob/master/dispatcher  вот ссылка на класс

Answer (score 0):

Ребята, решил тем, что пересоздал заново проект, убрал томкат, запустил через спрингбут. больше отличий вроде нет.